# How can I use aync/await in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

How can I use `async/await` in **javascript**?

How can I do this?

*Any help is appropriated?*

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=use+async%2Fawait+in+javascript

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but `async`/`await` does not get rid of promises. It  *embraces* them.

Comment: Which vendor runtime implementation are you using?

Comment: Your runtime appears to support async/await, so what is your question?

Comment: My question is there, I wanted a real comparative example of it, so I got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The purpose of **async/await** functions is to simplify the behavior
>   of using promises synchronously and to perform some behavior on a
>   group of Promises. Just like Promises are similar to structured
>   callbacks, **async/await** is similar to combining generators and
>   promises.

See this example:

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function add1(x) {
  var a = resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + await a + await b;
}

add1(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 2 seconds.
});

async function add2(x) {
  var a = await resolveAfter2Seconds(20);
  var b = await resolveAfter2Seconds(30);
  return x + a + b;
}

add2(10).then(v => {
  console.log(v);  // prints 60 after 4 seconds.
});
```

An API that returns a Promise will result in a promise chain, and it splits the function into many parts. Consider the following code:

```
function getProcessedData(url) {
  return downloadData(url) // returns a promise
    .catch(e => {
      return downloadFallbackData(url); // returns a promise
    })
    .then(v => {
      return processDataInWorker(v); // returns a promise
    });
}
```

it can be rewritten with a single **async** function as follows:

```
async function getProcessedData(url) {
  let v;
  try {
    v = await downloadData(url); 
  } catch(e) {
    v = await downloadFallbackData(url);
  }
  return processDataInWorker(v);
}
```